# C# Ui freezes when calling a method

Tags: c#, function, methods, freeze

I got a function called Connect() this function takes about 2-3seconds because it use some api requests. Now I want to find a way that my Ui dont freeze while ill start this function.

```
    private void connectToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Connect() // << this tooks a lot of time
    }
```

I have tried to solve it with a thread

```
    private void connectToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Thread(Connect).Start();
    }
```

and a backgroudnworker

```
    private void backgroundWorkerConnect_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Connect();
    }
```

but the programm still freezes.

```
   private void Connect()
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(Connect));
        }
        else
        {
            if (!connected)
            {
                connected = true;
                verbindenToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
                trennenToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
                InfoStripStatus.Text = "Status: Connected";

                irc.joinRoom(channel, BotConnectingMessage);
                chatThread = new Thread(getMessage);
                chatThread.Start();
                loadLoyalty();
                updateTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(timerViewer, null, 0, 60000);
            }
        }
    }
```

Maybe I'm just doing something wrong and hope someone can help me.

Comment: Starting a new thread is not supposed to freeze UI because it has its own thread

Comment: And the `Connect();` method doesn't rely or invoke anything on the UI-thread? If you replace whatever is in `Connect()` with `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);` does it still freeze the UI? (test it with the last two options)

Comment: Okay ill tryed it to replace the Connect() content with the sleep(3000) and there is now no more freeze. But i dont get it why because in the Connect() funktion is nothing who takes that long. Ill add the content of  Connect() in the top :)

Comment: okay can u maybe give me an example of that... PLEEAAASSEEE :D

Comment: Here is a nice sample about how to use a background worker and how to keep your UI responsive while a long action is being performed. https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx If you need to update UI controls from the background thread you should update the controls using their "Invoke" method.

Comment: Threading is not sometime you can make guess. **You have to learn it and use it properly.** Otherwise, you will always have program that do not works as expected. However, async programming or background worker hide most of the complexities so it is not that hard to do basic multithreading in C#.

Comment: @OliverLink: your `Connect()` method is trying to directly update the UI... you need to synchronize UI updates in a more non-preemptive manner.

Comment: Okay it is the updateTimer who freeze it with the api requests. but its strange only the first tick of this timer freeze the ui

Answer (score 2):

Using another thread (whether via `BackgroundWorker` or by creating one directly) to call a method that does nothing more than to invoke some code back on the UI thread and then wait for it, *is going to solve nothing*. The code you care about is still executing in the UI thread, blocking it.

You should use `async`/`await` with `Task.Run()` to handle your work:

```
private async void connectToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Connect();
}

private async Task Connect()
{
    if (!connected)
    {
        connected = true;
        verbindenToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
        trennenToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
        InfoStripStatus.Text = "Status: Connected";

        await Task.Run(() => irc.joinRoom(channel, BotConnectingMessage));
        chatThread = new Thread(getMessage);
        chatThread.Start();
        loadLoyalty();
        updateTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(timerViewer, null, 0, 60000);
    }
}
```

Depending on how slow `loadLoyalty()` is, you might also want `await Task.Run(loadLoyalty);` instead of just calling it directly.

The above will execute all of the code in the UI thread where it belongs, *except* the code you invoke via `Task.Run()`.

There are other ways that the code could be refactored, including an alternative that works with `BackgroundWorker` (i.e. just using `Control.Invoke()` to do the first four statements, and run the rest in the `Connect()` method directly). But IMHO the above using `async`/`await` is the best option today.

Comment: Thx mate after a bit of reading about asyn/await and Task it works with just a few changes

Answer (score 0):

Okay that looks interessting. I will try to transfer it to the other functions because I found out that it is the updateTimer which freeze it.

```
    private void timerViewer(object state)
    {
        irc.sendChatMessage("/mods");
        UpdateStream();
        UpdateChatters();
    } 

    private void UpdateStream()
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(UpdateStream));
        }
        else
        {
            StreamInformations = TwitchROClient.getStream(TwitchROClient.getIDbyUsername("xzaliax"));

            if (StreamInformations.stream != null)
            {

                viewers = StreamInformations.stream.Viewers;
                totalviews = StreamInformations.stream.channel.Views;

                if (followers == 0)
                {
                    followers = StreamInformations.stream.channel.Followers;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (followers < StreamInformations.stream.channel.Followers)
                    {
                        newFollower();
                    }
                    followers = StreamInformations.stream.channel.Followers;
                }


                InfoStripViewer.Text = "|  " + string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:N0}", viewers).Replace(',', '.') + " :Viewer";
                InfoStripFollower.Text = "|  " + string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:N0}", followers).Replace(',', '.') + " :Follower ";
                InfoStripTotalViewer.Text = "|  " + string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:N0}", totalviews).Replace(',', '.') + " :Total Viewers";
                InfoStripStream.Text = "|  Stream: Online";
            }
            else
            {
                InfoStripViewer.Text = "|  -- :Viewer";
                InfoStripFollower.Text = "|  -- :Follower";
                InfoStripTotalViewer.Text = "|  -- :Total Viewers";
                InfoStripStream.Text = "|  Stream: Offline";
            }
        }
    }
    private void UpdateChatters()
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(UpdateChatters));
        }
        else
        {
            ChannenlChatters = TwitchROClient.getChatters(channel);
            lbViewer.Items.Clear();

            if (ChannenlChatters != null)
            {
                if (ChannenlChatters.AllChatters != null)
                {
                    tbChat.Text += "Checking the viewer list..." + Environment.NewLine;
                    if (ChannenlChatters.AllChatters.Admins.Count >= 0) lbViewer.Items.Add("_____________Admins_____________");
                    foreach (string admin in ChannenlChatters.AllChatters.Admins)
                    {
                        lbViewer.Items.Add(String.Format("{0,5}", admin));
                    }
                    if (ChannenlChatters.AllChatters.Admins.Count >= 0) lbViewer.Items.Add("");

                    if (ChannenlChatters.AllChatters.Staff.Count >= 0) lbViewer.Items.Add("_____________Stuff______________");
                    foreach (string stuff in ChannenlChatters.AllChatters.Staff)
                    {
                        lbViewer.Items.Add(String.Format("{0,5}", stuff));
                    }
                    if (ChannenlChatters.AllChatters.Staff.Count >= 0) lbViewer.Items.Add("");

                    if (ChannenlChatters.AllChatters.GlobalMods.Count >= 0) lbViewer.Items.Add("___________Global Mods__________");
                    foreach (string globalmods in ChannenlChatters.AllChatters.GlobalMods)
                    {
                        lbViewer.Items.Add(String.Format("{0,5}", globalmods));
                    }

                    if (ChannenlChatters.AllChatters.GlobalMods.Count >= 0) lbViewer.Items.Add("");
                    foreach (string globalMods in ChannenlChatters.AllChatters.GlobalMods)
                    {
                        lbViewer.Items.Add(String.Format("{0,5}", globalMods));
                    }

                    if (ChannenlChatters.AllChatters.Moderators.Count >= 0) lbViewer.Items.Add("___________Moderators___________");
                    foreach (string moderator in ChannenlChatters.AllChatters.Moderators)
                    {
                        lbViewer.Items.Add(String.Format("{0,5}", moderator));
                    }

                    if (ChannenlChatters.AllChatters.Viewers.Count >= 0) lbViewer.Items.Add("____________Viewers_____________");
                    foreach (string viewers in ChannenlChatters.AllChatters.Viewers)
                    {
                        lbViewer.Items.Add(String.Format("{0,5}", viewers));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

so i will read more about ascny and await and test it a bit

Comment: Your timer callback does the same thing your click handler did. It runs _everything_ on the UI thread. Naturally, this blocks the UI thread while it's working. Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to give any specific advice, but the basic solution is still the same: don't block the UI thread for long-running operations. You seem to be doing I/O so there may already be async methods you can call. If not, you can fallback on the `await Task.Run()` idiom, as in my answer posted here.